# Windows MongoDB Journal very large

Tags: windows, mongodb, diskspace, journaling

I'm using a MongoDB Server v3.6 on my Windows machine with the following configuration file:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "C:/data/log/mongodb.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  engine: wiredTiger
  dbPath: "C:/data/db"
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: "127.0.0.1"
  ipv6: false
  ssl:
    mode: "preferSSL"
    PEMKeyFile: "C:/data/ssl/cert.pem"
    PEMKeyPassword: "****"
    allowInvalidCertificates: true
    allowInvalidHostnames: true
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

When I write large amounts of Data into arrays in a collection via push updates, lots of files pop up in C:/data/db/journal/
They are called WiredTigerLog.<somenumber> and WiredTigerPreplog.<somenumber>, each one being 102,4 MB large.
From what I have read the journal is supposed to clear out when the changes have been written to the disk. Even when I stop the program that writes that data into the database, those files remain until I shutdown the database. I have had two hard crashes because I ran out of disk space. after about an hour of data importing, the journal swells up to 100 GB+.

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to mongodb server version 4.05. The journal files now get deleted. Still about 10 or so files pop up, but they eventually get removed, even when continuously writing large amounts of data.